# @LazyLoading and JsonOutput

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, jackson

Working on a project which uses Spring/JPA/Rest.
We have a class which has a @OneToMany field(say Student in the example below) which is marked for LAZY loading. However, when we test the output in postman, we see the complete json for the Course and all the student details.

```
public class CourseList{

private String Course;
//other fields

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    
private <Set>Student students;

//Getters and Setters
```

}

My understanding of Lazy Loading is that the fetch for the database happens only on **explicit call to the particular field**. We should expect to see only the Course details coming up in the json and not the address details..why are we seeing address details too?

Can someone help clarify, if my understanding of LazyLoading is incorrect or whether it doesn't apply in this case for some reason? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Spring Data Jpa ?

Comment: Yes, Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON library will read all the properties of the object recursively in order to generate the output. So it is accessing the students set.

You have three possible outcomes here, from my experience:

1. The JSON serialization happens outside the JPA session so the object is *detached*. Since the students set is lazy loaded you will get an exception.
2. The JSON serialization happens inside the JPA session so when the JSON library accesses the students set then the data is fetched from the database.
3. The JSON serialization happens outside the JPA session but you have, somehow, accessed the students set before that and inside the JPA session. The data was fetched and is available on the detached object.

I've had this issue and I've forced the third option. My first try gave me the exception (option 1) but then I forced a read from the lazy loaded set just to fetch the data for the JSON serialization.

Comment: In point 2, are you saying that JSON serialisation is forced for LAZY objects too ? This defeats the purpose of LAZY or is it that a tool like Postman is doing this forceful loading ?

Comment: Your **JSON library** doesn't know anything about lazy Loading is what the answer is essentially saying. In the absence of any further processing instructons, it  attempts to  serialize the lazy field just like any other field: this triggers a Database load which may or may not succeed depending on your JPA provider and various other things. That's why there exists a Jackson Hibernate module to assist with such issues: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot registers an OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Spring boot default configuration `spring.jpa.open-in-view = true`.
If you want to disable that behaviour, add the configuration `spring.jpa.open-in-view = false`.

> Register OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor. Binds a JPA EntityManager
>   to the thread for the entire processing of the request.

Comment: Thanks @jackk ! that seems to be the right answer. However, a little detail on why this happens could help me and others who read this thread later. I googled a bit and found this wonderful resource that explains this problem in hibernate and jpa but no issues in eclipselink. http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.in/2010/12/jpa-lazy-loading-and-view-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

```
// ^_^?
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    
public Link Student student;
```

You want to return `CourseList` including `List<Student>`, You need to create the `Response` or `Student` entity you must be sure that no `@ManyToOne` to `CourseList`, otherwise happens StackOverflow Error.

This tutorial also refers to that problem: [Spring Data : JPA (Hibernate) One To Many Relationships and N+1 Query Problem](https://w3stacks.com/spring-data/spring-data-jpa-hibernate-one-to-many-relationships-and-n-1-query-problem)

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstood my question. I aware of the infinite loop problem (which the link refers to). My issue is about why postman JSON output is showing up the lazy loaded Student Object in the result